# Android Certificate Installation

Tags: android, certificate

I observed that some of the secure certificates are failed to installed in android device. The message shows the certificate get installed successfully. But it does not get listed in "Trusted Credentials" list. But I could not identify the reason for it.

Can some one give me help me to identify the reason behind this failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent a lot of time trying to find an answer to this (I need Android to see StartSSL certificates). Conclusion: Android 2.1 and 2.2 allow you to import certificates, but only for use with WiFi and VPN. There is no user interface for updating the list of trusted root certificates, but there is discussion about adding that feature. It’s unclear whether there is a reliable workaround for manually updating and replacing the cacerts.bks file.

Details and links: http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2010/12/android-certificates/. In that post, see the link to Android bug 11231--you might want to add your vote and query to that bug.